# Some Biolinum KeyCap missing as soon as `luatexja-fontspec` is loaded

Tags: luatexja, biolinum

The following MCE compiles like a charm and provides nice keyboard keys. But as soon as `luatexja-fontspec` is loaded, some characters are missing (here ⌥).

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
\usepackage{biolinum}
\begin{document}
Foo
\LKeyEnter
\LKeyOptionKey
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to circumvent this problem, for instance by limiting the scope of `luatexja-fontspec`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

luatexja maps every char into two classes: ALchar and JAchar. The second is always typeset with a japanese font. You can force that a char is typeset as ALchar once with `\ltjalchar`, you can change the status of a char with `\ltjdefcharrange`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
\usepackage{biolinum}


\begin{document}
Foo
\LKeyEnter
\LKeyOptionKey

{\biolinumkey\ltjalchar 8997}

\ltjdefcharrange{4}{8997}

\LKeyOptionKey

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is nice but I would be more interested by the other way round since my real document makes use of JAchar only exceptionally. So, is there a way for the ALchar to be the default and consider JAchar only locally?

Comment: yes there is a counterpart to \ltjalchar, and the documentation also describes how to reset the ranges (and all the defaults).

Comment: Thanks but, sorry, I must admit I'm a bit lost in this documentation and couldn't find how to reset the ranges (and all the defaults).