# “\end occurred when \ifnum ... was incomplete” with both tikz and luatexja

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, warnings, luatexja

The following MCE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
% \usepackage{luatexja}
\begin{document}
\tikz{\coordinate[yshift=\the\ht\strutbox];}
\end{document}
```

compiles without anything suspect but, if the `luatexja` package is loaded, the `.log` file contains (strangely as neither a warning nor an error):

```
(\end occurred when \ifnum on line 25 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \if on line 25 was incomplete)
```

Who is the culprit :

- the `luatexja` package ?
- the code `tikz{\coordinate[yshift=\ht\strutbox];}`, whose erroneous nature is revealed by `luatexja` ?

### Edit

Here is an (excerpt of an) example of failing real world usage (the real document contains reviews of both `ProfCollege` and `hanzibox` packages):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ProfCollege}
\usepackage{luatexja}
\begin{document}
\Pourcentage[Calculer]{15}{39}

\verb+\hanzibox*[frametype=none]{我}[wo3][moi]\\[1ex]+
\end{document}
```

Comment: See 11.5 \strutbox in the luatex-ja documentation.

Comment: I couldn't imagine a whole subsection of this documentation could be devoted to `\strutbox` :) Since `\tikz{\coordinate[yshift=\the\ht\strutbox];}` is part of a command of the package `ProfCollege` I'm using, I can't change it. I'm facing the same problem as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/643376/18401: my real document makes use of `luatex-ja` features only exceptionally. So, is there a way to load them only locally in order they don't interfere with other parts of the document?

Comment: well luatex-ja is if you skim the documentation a quite intrusive package. Are you sure you want to use it?

Comment: Well, not sure: it is the only solution I found for a document, compiled with `lualatex`, which has to display in a (single) listing (typeset in monospaced font) both Latin and Chinese characters. I load it with `\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
\ltjsetparameter{jacharrange={-9}} \setmainjfont{FandolSong}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works, but the length you get is quite unpredictable, because it depends on the current text direction.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{luatexja}
\begin{document}

\tikz{\coordinate[yshift=\the\expandafter\ht\expanded{\strutbox}];}

\end{document}
```

It also works when `\strutbox` is just a box register name, because it's unexpandable and so `\expanded` returns `\strutbox`.

In order to make this work with `ProfCollege`, you can patch the macros in the package that use the construction

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ProfCollege}
\usepackage{luatexja}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% the abstract version of the above
\newcommand{\getstrut}[1]{%
  \the\expandafter#1\expanded{\strutbox}%
}
% the internal commands of ProfCollege to patch
\patchcmd{\TikzPH}{\the\dp\strutbox}{\getstrut\dp}{}{}
\patchcmd{\TikzPHD}{\the\dp\strutbox}{\getstrut\dp}{}{}
\patchcmd{\TikzPHD}{\the\dp\strutbox}{\getstrut\dp}{}{}
\patchcmd{\TikzPB}{\the\ht\strutbox}{\getstrut\ht}{}{}
\patchcmd{\TikzPBD}{\the\ht\strutbox}{\getstrut\ht}{}{}
\patchcmd{\TikzPBD}{\the\ht\strutbox}{\getstrut\ht}{}{}
\patchcmd{\TikzRH}{\the\ht\strutbox}{\getstrut\ht}{}{}
\patchcmd{\TikzRB}{\the\dp\strutbox}{\getstrut\dp}{}{}
% the user level command to patch
\patchcmd{\FlecheLineaireH}{\ht\strutbox}{\getstrut\ht}{}{}

\begin{document}

\Pourcentage[Calculer]{15}{39}

\verb+\hanzibox*[frametype=none]{我}[wo3][moi]\\[1ex]+

\begin{center}
\Propor[
  Stretch=1.25,
  Math,
  GrandeurA=Hauteur $h$ (cm),
  GrandeurB=\begin{tabular}{c}Volume (en cm$^3$) d'un cylindre\\ de rayon \Lg{5} et
            de hauteur $h$\end{tabular},
  Largeur=0.75cm
]{2/$50\pi$,3/$75\pi$,5/}
\end{center}
\FlecheLineaireH{1}{2}{3}{$+$}
\FlecheLineaireB{1}{2}{3}{$+$}

\end{document}
```

The only user level command that uses `\ht\strutbox` is `\FlecheLineaireH`, quite strangely without `\the`, but I copied the example from the package documentation and it seems to work.

The previous *caveat* still applies: if you use different text directions as allowed by `luatexja`, you'll get into troubles.

[image]

Comment: Nice! But I can't rely on this since this `\tikz{\coordinate[yshift=\the\ht\strutbox];}` comes from a third party package. I guess the “\end occurred when \ifnum ... was incomplete” is harmless.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Ask the third party package's authors to patch.

Comment: Since this package is `ProfCollege`, devoted to French math teachers, I guess the author will consider it is not worth it. And your warning is scary :)

Comment: @DenisBitouzé There are ten occurrences of `\the<dim>\strutbox` where `<dim>` is either `\ht` or `\dp`. You can patch them yourself in your document.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé If you add an example of failing real world usage, I can direct you on how to do the patch: I'm not going to study the package.

Comment: Example of failing real world usage added.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Added the required patches

Comment: Very nice addition! Considering that, in most cases, `ProfCollege` is likely to not be used with `luatexja`, do you think it is worth for the author to make these changes? I mean: is it generally safer for his package to incorporate these changes?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé This works when `\strutbox` has the standard meaning and, in my opinion, is better than using directly `\the\ht\strutbox`, but opinions may differ.